# Suggested lsb-core installation procedure fails

Tags: package-management

While trying to install `lsb-core`, I get the following error:

```
Err:1 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu zesty/universe i386 libfreeimage3 i386 3.17.0+ds1-5build1   404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.26 80]
```

Additional errors appear about not finding the page. I ping the IP address and it is real.  Have the files been removed? If so, the installation scripts or must be updated.  Any suggestions on how I can proceed?

Comment: 17.04 is EOL. You should change all sources.list to old-releases or upgrade to 17.10.